# KornShell Implementation from a pseudo-code

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm trying to implement the extended euclidean algorithm given in pseudo-code below,  in KornShell (ksh).

I am having problems with the lines with ":=" - I don't know what those mean.

I'm also having problems with the multiple return variables.

How can I implement this?

```
function extended_gcd(a, b)
    x := 0    lastx := 1
    y := 1    lasty := 0
    while b ≠ 0
        quotient := a div b
        (a, b) := (b, a mod b)
        (x, lastx) := (lastx - quotient*x, x)
        (y, lasty) := (lasty - quotient*y, y)       
    return (lastx, lasty)
```

Comment: The psudo code IS NOT korn shell. Are you trying to implement this psudo code in korn shell?

Comment: Also. DONT implement this in ksh. This is not what ksh was designed for and it will be unessicarily difficult to use korn shell to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:= part :

:= is not for shell scripting , for assignments we use simple "=" in scripts ie 
     var="abcd" ;

:= is available in other tools though , like in make -- where it stands for immediate assignment.

what immediate assignment means is that the variable gets assigned a value the moment its parsed.

there are also other variants available like =? ... etc.

fxn return value part :

its a basic rule that a function can return only a single value.

But iff you are intrested in being able to use multiple variables outside the function body then -- bash/korn/shell in general dont have any specific concept as a local variable .

by default what ever variables you have in a script are global ie available throughout .... but within the scope of the current shell only .

you would need to export the variables to make them available in a child shell.
     syntax : export variable_name ;

Also you need to use {} braces to define a function body.  ie

```
  fxn_name()
    {
       var=$1;  ## if you want to use a variable 
      ...... 
        ....
       }
```

its invokation/call  is 
          fxn_name $arg ;

Comment: Inside `function foo {...}` (but *not* `foo () {...}` in some ksh implementions), you can get a "local" variable with the `typeset` command.